# One time query to sync time with NTP server

Tags: solaris, ntp

I do not plan to configure NTP client to sync with the NTP servers for my Solaris servers.

Is it possible that I connect to this NTP servers and sync the time on an ad-hoc basis?

Comment: Why are you setting out on the wrong path? It's trivial to configure NTP (whether `ntpd` or `xntpd`) to synchronise to a local server.

Comment: I am not familiar with the configuration of NTP client/service for Solaris.

Comment: What about https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aunix.stackexchange.com+solaris+ntp.conf

Comment: looks kind of confusing for me.

Comment: You haven't asked how to configure NTP to synchronise clients from a local server, nor how to set up that local server, so I can't answer such a question here. If you do ask that kind of question I'm sure you'll get answers. Please ensure you state whether your primary server needs to get time from the Internet or whether it's to run only from its local clock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ntpdate` command will have the answer of your question.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5166/ntpdate-1m.html

Answer (score 1):

You could manually sync on an adhoc basis, but based on the simplicity of setting up NTP, you might as well set it up for your servers.

You didn't note your version of Solaris, but the configuration file is going to be similar across the majority of the platforms since most vendors use the same source code for NTP.

Sample simple configuration file for an NTP client  below.  You'll also usually see vendor samples in that same directory.

/etc/inet/ntp.conf:

```
server <NTP_SERVER1> prefer  
server <NTP_SERVER2>

peer <NTP_PEER_SERVER1> 
peer <NTP_PEER_SERVER2>

slewalways yes

driftfile /var/ntp/ntp.drift 
statsdir /var/ntp/ntpstats/
```

You can also refer to NTP.org's faq:

http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/